# How can I delete item from a nested XUL tree?

Tags: tree, nested, xul, removechild

I created a nested tree using XUL (no database was used to store items). I want to delete items from this tree by selecting the item (only 1 at a time) then click delete. I wrote Javascript function to delete as following but it does not work.

```
function delete(){
  var tree = document.getElementById("treeId");    
  currentPos = tree.currentIndex;    
  var currentItem = tree.contentView.getItemAtIndex(currentPos);
  var parent = currentItem.getParent();
  parent.removeChild(currentItem);
}
```

I guess getParent() is not the right method but did not find any other method. Can someone give me some hints please.
 Thanks

Comment: I also tried var parent= currentItem.parentNode; but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was my mistake. I just realized that delete cannot be used as a name of function.

Comment: The function that I wrote above must work. You just need to use another name for the function instead of delete().