# How to add and remove rows from a Firefox Addon XUL Tree

Tags: javascript, tree, firefox-addon, xul

In my Firefox extension I have a simple tree which has two columns. I am trying to programatically:

- Add a row
- Remove all rows

My XUL Tree:

```
<tree flex="1" id="mytree" hidecolumnpicker="true">

  <treecols>
    <treecol id="sender" label="Sender" flex="1"/>
    <treecol id="subject" label="Subject" flex="2"/>
  </treecols>

  <treechildren>

  </treechildren>

</tree>
```

Javascript I've tried to add rows:

```
// trying to add rows
var data = {
    {'sender' : 'John', 'subject' : 'something'},
    {'sender' : 'Adam', 'subject' : 'something else'},
    {'sender' : 'Bob', 'subject' : 'something else again'}
};

document.getElementById("mytree").view.data = data;
```

There are no errors with this, the tree just does not get the rows added. I know the code runs because if I add an `alert()` it fires.

Javascript I've tried to remove all rows:

```
var tree = document.getElementById("mytree");

tree.view.data = {};
tree.view.treeBox.rowCountChanged(0, -1);
```

This produces an error:

> document.getElementById("mytree").view.treeBox is undefined

**Edit:**

After Wladimir's suggestion to add the XUL elements directly, this will add a row:

```
var treeChildren = document.getElementById("my_tree_children");

var treeitem = document.createElement('treeitem');
var treerow = document.createElement('treerow');

var treecell_1 = document.createElement('treecell');
var treecell_2 = document.createElement('treecell');

treecell_1.setAttribute('label', 'John');
treecell_2.setAttribute('label', 'something');

treerow.appendChild(treecell_1);
treerow.appendChild(treecell_2);

treeitem.appendChild(treerow);

treeChildren.appendChild(treeitem);
```

Although hard coded in this example, the values for the cells (label attribute) will come from user input. What method of encoding/escaping should I use when putting user input directly into an attribute of a XUL element, to prevent XSS?

Comment: No, you should use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent) rather than `innerHTML`. But that's not the issue here - text to be displayed in a `treecell` should be put into the `label` attribute, see [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute).

Comment: @WladimirPalant you're absolutely right. It works with `setAttribute()`. One final issue - what is the best practice for preventing XSS on a XUL attribute, because the content will come from user input - see my edit.

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` :) Other DOM methods won't let you create tags when you didn't intend to.

Comment: @WladimirPalant thanks for the help. I will upvote you when possible (need +2 rep)

Comment: @ServerBloke: Sorry, I wasn't correct. +1 for your effort.

Comment: @linguini your first example of deleting worked for me - just needed to delete from the children instead of the tree root (to avoid deleting column headers). Did you delete the answer?

Comment: @ServerBloke: My answer wasn't appropriate according to `Wladimir Palant` so i deleted it. I shared the link here, you find the solution here<:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791433/how-can-i-delete-item-from-a-nested-xul-tree>

Comment: @linguini the one you linked to wouldn't work for me, but the first delete example did work (after a minor tweak). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me ask it this way: why *should* it work? The documentation tells us that [`tree.view`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tree#p-view) is an [`nsITreeView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsITreeView) instance. And `nsITreeView` has no property called `data`. Just because you can set this property nevertheless doesn't mean that it will do anything.

Now how would you actually put data into a `tree` widget? The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tree) explains that there are several tree types, depending on type the data might come from a different place. You probably want to use the default option - a content tree. This means that you need to create `treeitem` elements for each row in your data and add these to the `treechildren` element - as shown in the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tree#A_tree_with_several_columns). You can generate these elements dynamically using the usual DOM methods.

The `tree` widget can also generate its content automatically from an RDF or XML datasource. If you have your data in a JavaScript object however, the only alternative would be creating a custom `nsITreeView` implementation and assigning it to `tree.view`. But this is not quite trivial and usually an overkill.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion - see my edit in the question, I still can't add a row even that way.

Comment: I think you've added the row correctly, it simply doesn't have any text.